# cordova 8 send silent sms

Tags: java, android, cordova

i use this plugin https://github.com/rampicos/Cordova-SMS-Plugin for sending sms silently (send a secret key), but the plugin says, your application must be default SMS App to send sms

question :

1. how to send silent sms without being a default SMS App

Answer (score 1):

Security restrictions do not allow apps to send sms without explicit user consent (per message)
Similar riules apply for making phone calls. 
Whatever it is you are trying to accomplish, it is probably possible (easier?) with xhr.